# Каково происхождение поговорки "кто в лес, кто по дрова"?

Tags: фразеология

Строка из басни «Музыканты» (1808) Ивана Андреевича Крылова (1769 — 1844). **Запели молодцы: кто в лес, кто по дрова.** Обычно о пении, игре на музыкальных инструментах.

Это все знают, но почему эта поговорка означает "вразнобой, вразброд, несогласованно, нестройно"? Ведь по дрова обычно именно в лес и ходили, то есть не в разные стороны пошли, а в одно и то же место.

Что же тут несогласованного?

Answer (score 1):

Если исходить из варианта "[Кто в лес да по дрова; кто рубль, кто полтора](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9A%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%3B%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0&oq=%D0%9A%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%3B%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.1830j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)", то более или менее ясно: в огороде, а в Киеве:

разнобой таки.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Интересно, что в полном варианте поговорка еще более непонятна, так как союз ДА соединительный. Тогда уж точно несогласованность отсутствует. И продолжение мне кажется странным.

Comment: Это "да" как бы причинное, не знаю имени.

Answer (score 0):

> ДРОВА́, дров, -а́м, мн. Распиленные и обычно расколотые на поленья
>   деревья, идущие на топливо. Березовые дрова. Сухие дрова. Вязанка
>   дров. Наколоть дров. (Малый академический словарь, МАС)

Лес валят, как правило, для заготовки стволов, т.е. строевого леса и пиловочника. Отходы древесины отправляют на дровяник (дровницу, поленицу), и в ходе сушки они становятся годными для топки дровами. Лесоруб запускает, а заканчивает процесс истопник. Нужные и необходимые, но несовместимые — во времени и пространстве — у них обязанности.